# jsf additional confirmation on dropdown select

Tags: jsf

I have a situation, where user have a dropdown menu with single choice. 
Available choices in two groups:
-time group - hour, day, week
-location - street, city, state
And there are also a filters.

When the choice is made there are two scenarios:
-if he chose time group, when before where chosen time group before- nothing happens. Table displays different set of data. That's all.
-if he chose time group, when there was a location group chosen, or he chooses location group when there was a time group **PLUS IF THERE ARE FILTERS** form needs to display warning box, with additional confirmation. 
When User press YES button on this confirmation box, then all filters must be deleted, and requested data displayed without any filters. When he hits NO button, nothing happens - confirmation box disappears, and old set of data with filters is displayed


'Where is the problem?' you may ask. Well, I have no clue how to make this confirmation box:/
All the things that I described are working just fine, but this confirmation box is something I just don't get.
Thanks for any help

**EDIT**

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{compareBean.xAxis}" styleClass="chosen-select">
     <f:selectItem noSelectionOption="true" itemLabel="Chose..."/>
      <f:selectItems value="#{compareBean.getXAxisOptions()}"
                     var="attrib"
                     itemLabel="#{attrib.value}"
                     itemValue="#{attrib.key}"/>
       <f:ajax execute="@this" render=":additionalGraphs" onevent="drawChart"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

and

```
public void setXAxis(Long xAxis){
    if (checkIfGroupIsTheSame()){
        filters.clear();
    }
    this.xAxis = xAxis;
```

}

Comment: So you don't know how to show the confirm box?

Comment: No - I don't know how to show confirm box, when there are filters added and different group is chosen.

Comment: If you paste the code you're using now it'll be easier to help you.

Comment: like you requested I added my code - it's basic select one menu, with ajax event